# Is there a model MultiField (any way to compose db models Fields in Django)? Or why would not that be a useful concept?

Tags: django, composition, extensibility

When building a Django application, we were exposed to (forms) `MultiValueField` and `MultiWidget`.

They seem like an interesting approach to compose their respective base classes, giving more modularity.

---

Yet, now it seems to us that the actual piece that would make those two shine bright would be a `db.models.MultiField`. Here is the reasoning:

- It seems that, when using a ModelForm, Django is enforcing a strict 1-to-1 association between a models.Field and a forms.Field. Now, with `forms.MultiValueField`, despite this strict 1-to-1 association, you can have a single `models.Field` actually associated to the numerous `forms.Field` composing the `forms.MultiValueField`.
- Yet, it is limited to the case where a single `models.Field` maps more naturally to several `forms.Field`. What seems very interesting would be the ability to associate any number of `models.Fields` to any number of `forms.Field`. The *only* piece that seems to be missing to get there is an hypothetical `models.MultiField`. It could communicate with the exterior through a `compress()` method (see. `MultiValueField`), and potentially a `decompress()` method in the other direction (see `MultiWidget`).

The questions would then be (assuming this requirement is not emerging from a misunderstanding of Django): Is there a way to compose `modelds.Field` in Django ? If not, why is such an empowering concept not implemented in this great framework ;) ?

---

**EDIT:** To give a motivating example, imagine we want to implement a **partial date** (a date that can be precise to a day, or just precise to a month and a year, or alternatively just a year), with a `Model` following [the one presented in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30186603/1027706), i.e.:

- a `DateField`, representing the date
- a `CharField`, to indicate whether the date is *complete* or *month + year* or *just year*.

This model is working just fine with the default `ModelForm`, but now we want to introduce some consistency check: if a date is only precise to the month (*month + year* or *just year*), its day part should be **1**, and if it is only precise to the year, its month part should also be **1**.

This is a **cross-fields** check (two different `Field`s from the `ModelForm` needs to be accessed to complete it), so it has to be implemented at the `Form.clean()` level. This check would need to be copy-pasted in each form containing a partial date, which goes against the DRY cherished by Django.

Now let's imagine Django is providing this hypothetical `models.MultiField`, which would be a composite `models.Field`. We could define a `PartialDate`class deriving from `MultiField` and containing the two leaf fields defined above (`DateField`  and `CharField`). We could now say that the **form** field corresponding to this *single* **model** field (in a `ModelForm`) is a class derived from `forms.MultiValueField`. This class **could implement the consistency check** above, at the **field level**: it is not a cross-field check anymore.

This way, we got rid of the code duplication: any model could use a `PartialDate` field, automatically making any `ModelForm`s mapping to it use the `forms.MultiValueField` implementing the consistency check, whose code was only written in one place.

(This is a simple example, it is easy to imagine it can get way more complex in production code, with consistency check you do not want to copy paste)

Answer (score 0):

Possible: Yes. You could either subclass djangos model class, or monkey-patch that class into the existing model module.

Just (educated) guessing: I think it is not missing, but not needed.

In DB-Applications, combined fields will almost always come with special business rules. So you will have to implement a different display and validation for each one of them anyway.

Which you already can easily do in the models.Form.

Maybe you should look at customization of models.Form?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You said: "*In DB-Applications, combined fields will almost always come with special business rules. So you will have to implement a different display and validation for each one of them anyway.*"  I could not agree more: and this is exactly the reason why I think a composite `models.Field` would be a great tool toward code reuse and factorization. I added a motivating example illustrating this, but basically you do not want to tie you custom logic to a specific `Form`: instead, you want this logic to be used by all forms showing your composite field.

Comment: It's just easier to reuse the form. The best way to implement your use-case would be a custom model field, that is using two DB-columns.

Comment: "*The best way to implement your use-case would be a custom model field, that is using two DB-columns*". I would very much agree with that. And this is exactly why I am asking this question (where is the `models.MultiField` ?), because it would seem like an important tool allowing a new kind of extensibility for the framework.

Comment: Note the difference: Custom model field, using two DB-columns: Already there, you just have to subclass model.Field and implement your logic. Your MultiField - joining two fields - adds another abstraction (distraction?) layer.

Comment: "*Your MultiField - joining two fields - adds another abstraction (distraction?) layer*". If we assume that abstraction layers over the composite pattern are a nuisance, then should not it stand for `forms.MultiValueField` and `MultiWidget`? Because of those 2 classes, I was under the impression that Django was encouraging this pattern: then with this attitude in mind, I fail to see a good rationale against the `models.MultiField`. It would be bringing the composite already present in other related classes to the model layer (after that, it would be the users' choice to use it or not).

Comment: Don't overestimate the architectural matureness of Django ;-) But besides that, these abstractions extend functionality. Judging by their code, the primary reason of their existence is some "oops, someone missed something important here" anyway.
If you just want to use Django, i would use a custom model field, that handles and encloses the DB-Columns.
If you want to extend Django migrations (which, i guess, will be the real problem) than i am sure the Django folks working on it will appreciate help.