# In Django, is it possible to have several models.Field mapping to a single field in a ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Almost everything is in the title.
In Django, by default each `models.Field` on your model matches to one separate `forms.Field` in the auto generated list of fields of a `ModelForm`.

Is it somehow possible to manually go against that, and have a single `forms.Field` associated to **several** of the `models.Field`s ?

(This question is closely [related to this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32014748/1027706).)

Comment: ... so where is a problem? override clean_field and save methods for your needs ... have you read the django docs about modelforms before ask question? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: @madzohan It is great to see that you know an obvious solution to this problem. Do not hesitate to post it as an answer to the question (if it is not a duplicate from content already existing on **SO**).