# Django ModelMultipleChoiceField not saving

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, manytomanyfield

I got a ManyToMany field with the django-admin's `ModelMultipleChoiceField` working:

[image: Working ManyToMany Admin UI Element]

When I add one element from the left side to the right side and click "Save" in the admin UI, then reload the Detail-Page where this `ModelMultipleChoiceField` is showing up, the saved elements can clearly be seen on the right side.

The code for this working model looks like this:

```py
# project/account/models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from model_utils import Choices

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followers', blank=True, symmetrical=False)
```

```py
# project/account/forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple
from .models import User

class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    following = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
            verbose_name='Following',
            is_stacked=False
        )
    )
    followers = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
            verbose_name='Followers',
            is_stacked=False
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('following', 'followers')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['following'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                queryset=User.objects.all().exclude(pk=self.instance.pk),
                required=False,
                widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
                    verbose_name='Following',
                    is_stacked=False
                )
            )
            self.fields['followers'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                queryset=User.objects.all().exclude(pk=self.instance.pk),
                required=False,
                widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
                    verbose_name='Followers',
                    is_stacked=False
                )
            )
            self.fields['followers'].initial = self.instance.followers.all()
```

```py
# project/account/admin.py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from .models import User
from .forms import UserChangeForm, UserCreationForm

class Admin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    model = get_user_model()

    fieldsets = (
        ('Following / Followers', {'fields': ('following', 'followers')}),
    )

admin.site.register(User, Admin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

This will save the modified realtions in the admin panel as expected.

**But now I got another usecase where I want to have three different `ModelMultipleChoiceField`s for the same model:**

```py
# project/account/models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from model_utils import Choices
from shared_models.models import Badge

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    badges = models.ManyToManyField(Badge, related_name='owners', blank=True)
```

```py
# project/shared_models/models.py
from django.db import models
from model_utils import Choices

class Badge(models.Model):
    BADGE_TYPES = Choices('bronze', 'silver', 'gold')

    type = models.CharField(choices=BADGE_TYPES, max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=1500)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'shared_models'

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.description = value
```

```py
# project/account/forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple
from shared_models.models import Badge
from .models import User

def general_model_multiple_choice_field_filter_type(model, verbose_name, filter_by_type):
    queryset = model.objects.all()
    if filter:
        queryset = queryset.filter(type=filter_by_type)
    return forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=queryset,
        required=False,
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
            verbose_name=verbose_name,
            is_stacked=False
        )
    )

class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    bronze_badges = general_model_multiple_choice_field_filter_type(model=Badge, verbose_name='Bronze Badges', filter_by_type='bronze')
    silver_badges = general_model_multiple_choice_field_filter_type(model=Badge, verbose_name='Silver Badges', filter_by_type='silver')
    gold_badges = general_model_multiple_choice_field_filter_type(model=Badge, verbose_name='Gold Badges', filter_by_type='gold')

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('bronze_badges',
                  'silver_badges',
                  'gold_badges')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['bronze_badges'] = general_model_multiple_choice_field_filter_type(Badge,
                                            'Bronze Badges',
                                            filter_by_type='bronze')
            self.fields['silver_badges'] = general_model_multiple_choice_field_filter_type(Badge,
                                            'Silver Badges',
                                            filter_by_type='silver')
            self.fields['gold_badges'] = general_model_multiple_choice_field_filter_type(Badge,
                                            'Gold Badges',
                                            filter_by_type='gold')
```

```py
# project/account/admin.py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from .models import User
from django.db.models import Q
from .forms import UserChangeForm, UserCreationForm

class Admin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    model = get_user_model()

    fieldsets = (
        ('Badges', {'fields': ('bronze_badges', 'silver_badges', 'gold_badges')}),
    )

admin.site.register(User, Admin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

But now, when I try to add some badges to the "Chosen" Section of the UI element, then click on "Save", reload the page, the selected items are still on the left side and the right side will stay empty. The post request responded with 302.

[image: Not saving ModelMultipleChoiceField]

So how can I get django to save modifications to the User.badges field?

**EDIT** found a question which perfectly asks for what I need: [Is there a model MultiField (any way to compose db models Fields in Django)? Or why would not that be a useful concept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014748/is-there-a-model-multifield-any-way-to-compose-db-models-fields-in-django-or)

Comment: I don't know why you think this would work. You haven't done anything to tell Django where to save the elements selected in those fields, nor where to get the data to prepopulate them subsequently.

Comment: I am pretty new to django. Could you show me how to tell django that it should use my User.badges model-field for saving? The pre-population seems to work as you can see and I am not even sure why it works sometimes and sometimes not...

Comment: Your user model defines `badges` as a ManyToManyField, but your ModelForm doesn't use that field, but `bronze_badges` instead. Since your form is saving a User, it can't do anything with a `bronze_badges` field. Make sure your `User` model has `bronze_badges`, `silver_badges` and `gold_badges` fields and also make sure your User model is registered in the settings (so it's what gets used by `get_user_model()`)

Comment: Thanks, already understood, the question is rather: How can I filter the badges by their type in the admin UI, but still store them to one and the same field "bagdes" in the User model? Or would you suggest having a model "Bagde" without the field "type" and having it 3 times instead? What's the best approach?

Comment: Or is it also possible to use "badges" in the form 3 times, once for "bronze" once for "silver", and last for "gold" badges? instead of the "bronze_bagdes", "silver_badges" and "gold_badges" fields?

Comment: Ok, you guys pointed me into the right direction, at least I now knew WHAT to read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/ and
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/
... those helped me a lot. Still trying to figure out how I can customly map a model's field to multiple different form fields at the same time...

Comment: Just found a question which perfectly asks for the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014748/is-there-a-model-multifield-any-way-to-compose-db-models-fields-in-django-or

Comment: I have come to the conclution that I will just use 3 different model fields for each type of badge in my User model... it works.