# What are good approaches to Django yearless date ranges

Tags: django

I need to store start and ending dates to save holidays.
I don't care about the year part of dates, as a holiday will repeat every year.

Also I need to be able to query this dates to see if a random datetime is in the range. And even when I don't want years stored, the query must understand that a holiday can start in one year and end next year (i.e. Dec 25th to Jan 4th).

Previously I was storing the dates as DateTimeFields, then iterating over each stored holiday and checking if a given target date was inside the dates range. This was made in Python and forced me to evaluate the QuerySets into lists and finally add the value using something like `getattr(result, 'is_a_holiday', value)`

As performance issues have arise I want to move this into an annotation (so I can keep the queryset with select_related and prefetch_related data) and make the database (Postgresql) do the query part, but then I run into the problem that the database considers the year, and thus a date inside a holiday for this year is not considered inside a holiday the previous year or next year.

I've already tried django-yearlessdate and annotating with conditional expressions and F expressions (to check when a year changes) but it is not working as expected: when there are several holidays some of the condition cases don't match and I just get the default return value.

What are other/different approaches to this problem?

Comment: As I mentioned:  
*> Previously I was storing the dates as DateTimeFields, then iterating over each stored holiday and checking if a given target date was inside the dates range. This was made in Python and forced me to evaluate the QuerySets into lists and finally add the value using something like getattr(result, 'is_a_holiday', value)*
This works but leads to performance issues  

*> I've already tried django-yearlessdate and annotating with conditional expressions and F expressions (to check when a year changes) but it is not working as expected...*  
This doesn't work

Comment: Show us your code, please.

Comment: (that is likely why you got a downvote by the way)

Comment: I don't see how any code is relevant when I'm asking for advice on different approaches to this problem. I'm not looking on a way to fix my code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hola javi, esta consulta està relacionada? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134526/date-conveniences-validation-display-etc-for-partial-dates-in-django

Comment: thanks for pointing to that one, it's related to partial dates but not to ranges

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need year, you can create two separate fields in your model to hold month and day separately:

```
class Holiday(...):
    month = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    day = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

Then to find holidays between a given range, you can do this:

```
from_date = <datetime object>
to_date   = <datetime object>

Holiday.objects.filter(month__range[from_date.month, to_date.month], 
                       day__range[from_date.day, to_date.day]
                      )
```